# Prevent mouse over to give focus in ConEmu

Tags: terminal, mouse, conemu, focus

In ConEmu when I have multiple panes active, a pane will get the focus when I move the mouse cursor over it, even if I don't click on the pane.

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: Suggestions about better control grouping are appreciated https://conemu.github.io/en/Issues.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Under `Settings`, `Keys & Macro`, `Mouse` (or `Controls`, for older versions):
Uncheck `Activate split/pane on mouse hover`

Comment: The name of the setting is okay, but it moved under Main->Tabs. I used the "Search" functionality (found in the upper left corner of the settings window) to locate it after seeing the name of the option here.

Comment: It's inside `Mouse` subcategory, I've updated the author's answer.